# Link options on Select with React

Tags: reactjs, url, internationalization, i18next

I would like to change the URL on change of a select to change the language of the app

Here is my attempt :

```
<select name="lang" id="lang">
     <option value="fr"><a href="https://test.com/fr">FR </a></option>
     <option value="en"><a href="https://test.com/en">EN </a></option>
</select>
```

When there is a `<a>` tag, the `option` desappear from the `select`.
Any idea ?

PS : I'm using NextJS and i18n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant use href tags within option tags. You will need javascript to do so.

Why dont you read the documentation? https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Or you could do something like this:

```
  const router = useRouter();

  function handleChange(e){
    router.push(`/${e.target.value}`)
  }

  return (
    <select name="lang" id="lang" onChange={handleChange}>
      <option value="fr">FR </option>
      <option value="en">EN </option>
    </select>
  );
```

Comment: Hello. I read the doc, mi i18n works fine. It is just that I would like to diplay a select button on my header. I did'nt find this in the documentation

Comment: You have the following options: maybe use a list? ( ul, li) or use a programmatical approach, meaning: call afunction on select change and pass the values to programmatically change the language,

Comment: The push options is a great idea, but i need to replace the current language. Does the function replace() work here ?

Comment: according to the next/router doc, you have a local option you can use: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how is that even possible with native select. However, you can handle a change of select field and redirect with push or what method NextJS is using

Comment: Do you know if i can replace() in this case ? Because push() method will put '/en/fr' in the URL